# After Delete Row How To Reset Sqlite id value?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

i have created sqlite database as follow

```
        NSString * sqlStmt =@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SONGS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MOVIENAME TEXT, SONGNAME TEXT)";
```

after deleting row 7 in database the id values are 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9...  by using following code where idNumber =7.

```
 const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_SQliteDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"delete from SONGS where ID=%d",idNumber];
    const char *del_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    char *error ;
    if (sqlite3_exec(_SQliteDB,del_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
    { 
        NSLog(@"sucessfully delete");

    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"unable to delete");
    }
    sqlite3_close(_SQliteDB);
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"unable to open");
}
```

i need to rearrange that order as sequentially as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8?
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot modify the AUTOINCREMENT field. Please add a new int column like "order" for ordering, then you are able to add a new row with order value 7.

Comment: That's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (question about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem); describe what you are trying to achieve by doing this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the order as sequentially, ORDER BY is what you are looking for.

After deleting, retrieve records using select query as shown below :

```
NSString *select = @"SELECT * FROM SONGS ORDER BY ID"
```

For more detail about ORDER BY , refer to [link1](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) and for how to use it in iOS, refer to [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581464/sqlite-select-query-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't re-order IDs, because other tables may have reference for this ID. Because if any how you are able to do that then next problem will arise in front of you.

**For example:- You have rows 1, 2, 3 and you delete 2, then you have 1, 3. And you sorted this any how. Now Issue is when you going to add new item it starts with 4 not 3.**

In your case, I recommend using the [Row_Number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) if it's for a display reason.

There's no problem having gaps in a database.

Comment: In this case!  after delete the record 2, it should arrange 1,2,3 to 1,2

Answer (score 0):

You must define all data from database to new array or list.After that you must delete table and rewrite all data from array or list to database.

You can look for android studio solution ;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57862686/8363647